# How to automatically convert if-else if statement to switch

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Is there a hot key or easy way to replace an if-else if statement with a switch in IntelliJ?  I would prefer not to manually convert the if-else if statement to a switch.  I am looking to be able to highlight the if-else if statement and press a combination of keys or use a menu button.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Update**: as @christopheml pointed out in comments on another answer, "Replace If with Switch" seems to have disappeared in IntelliJ 2018.1. A bug has been filed [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189592).

---

There are IntelliJ intentions named "Replace If with Switch" and "Replace Switch with If". Check your preferences to see if those options are enabled. If so, I would expect that you would see a quickfix option (<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows) whenever IntelliJ can automatically handle the conversion from one to the other.

Comment: Having the same problem - it used to work for me earlier, so am not sure what happened. I highlight the if-else but it doesn't offer the replacement.. And the if-else is clearly replaceable with the switch. Any way to force search for replaceable clauses?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.

Comment: In case of a switch statement on String values, the right-hand side of the comparison needs to be a constant (static final) for the if statement to be converted to a switch.

Answer (score 40):

I just found out that you have to click on the first `if`, wait for the light bulb icon to appear and then choose `Replace if with Switch`.

Comment: And you must turn on the "quick assist bulb" in Java - Editor in Preference.

Answer (score 12):

Android studio (intelliJ idea):

Put your cursor on the `switch`/`if` statement and:

mac: <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd>

win: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: on the first ``if``

Answer (score 3):

Checkout settings
[image]

- Minimum number of 'if' conditions branches: 3
- Only suggest on null-safe expressions

Answer (score 2):

**If it doesn't offer the replacement** anymore, its probably because disabled feature on "Intentions". (Android studio (IntelliJ))

Solution is simple:

- File > Settings > Editor > Intentions - Search: "replace switch"

or

- File > Settings - Search: "replace switch" > Editor > Intentions

and check the blank checkbox

Comment: Even after adding the above option.. That option is not coming for me..

Comment: As of version 2018.1, IntelliJ does not have the "Replace If with Switch" intention, while the "Replace Switch with If" intention still exists.

Answer (score 0):

When selected if/switch in Eclipse, press Ctrl+1 or right-click -> Quick fix and suggestions will pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select by double clicking on switch keyword
2. Left Suggestion bulb will appear.
3. Click on suggestion to replace switch with if else.

This works on android studio. It worked in my case

Comment: The question was the other way around: if-else -> switch, not switch -> if-else