# Java: Problems in Changing for each loop to normal for loop in method

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the following method and I wanted to change the for each loops to normal for loops. So I tried something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < above.length(); i++) {
    char x = above.toCharArray();
    if (x == 'x') {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

But I know that's wrong. So, what's the right way to change these for each loops to normal for loops?

```
public static int neighbourconditions(String above, String same, String below){
    int counter = 0;
    if(above != null){
        for(char x : above.toCharArray()){
            if(x == 'x'){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (char x : same.toCharArray()){
        if (x == 'x'){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (below != null){
        for(char x : below.toCharArray()){
            if (x == 'x'){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: ***char x = above.toCharArray();*** that makes no sense and doesnt compile...

Comment: if you are using eclipse you can click on the 'for' and then Ctrl+1 which shows a menu where you can convert between the different types of for loops (Ctrl+1 works for other useful stuff too (e.g. convert switch-case to if)

Comment: I found this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259009/how-to-automatically-convert-if-else-if-statement-to-switch
maybe Alt+Enter also works for converting for loops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a basic `for` loop whose bounds are governed by the length of the string, which is the same as the size of the corresponding character array, e.g. the first loop:

```
for (char x : above.toCharArray()) {
    if (x == 'x') {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

would become this:

```
for (int x=0; x < above.length(); ++x) {
    if (above.charAt(x) == 'x') {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's no difference here if I write ++counter. Or should it really be ++counter?

Comment: @JavaJoker204 The isolated statements `counter++` and `++counter` are functionally identical, though they are different.  If we were to assign a variable to `counter++`, and `counter=3`, then the variable would be assigned to 3, and then the counter would be incremented.  If, on the other hand, we assigned a variable to `++counter`, and `counter=3`, then the variable would be assigned to 4.

Comment: @JavaJoker204 in my mind it should be only for fashion along with  `++x`. In your code returning `counter` it's only a matter of preference

Comment: My buddy told me that ++counter is faster in C++.  I didn't believe him, but then I decompiled a test program (Visual Studio), and ++counter did use fewer instructions!

Comment: @Jamie see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39306/1575188 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261743/1575188 if you like

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `above.toCharArray().length` and to get the value `above.toCharArray()[i]` and with collaboration with [@chillworld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179190/java-problems-in-changing-for-each-loop-to-normal-for-loop-in-method#comment79321064_46179235):

You can create an array of `char[] array = above.toCharArray();` outside the loop like this :

```
char[] array = above.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 'x') {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe an optimalisation would be declaring the Char[] outside the loop.

Comment: than you, this is a good point @chillworld i edit my answer with your solution

Comment: The first way creates 2 new arrays for each iteration. I would definitely avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that you would have to find the length of each string being passed to the method. Example if the content of above is equal to "some_randome_string" you would have to find the length of the string or how many characters are in the string. in this case that would be 19. then you would do;

```
        if <variable != null > {
           for (x = 0; x < 18 ; x++) {
       code block to be executed
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to count occurances of character x then you may try below or a regex:

```
String upAbove = above.replaceAll("x","");
int count = above.length() - upAbove.length();
```