# why is it saying Constant expression required?

Tags: java, android

```
public void displaySelectedListener(int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.dashboard:
            break;

        case R.id.income:
            break;

        case R.id.expense:
            break;

    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

I'm watching a tutorial video and the guy just wrote dashboard, income and expense without a problem, but for me it keeps on saying `Constant expression required`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005205/what-causes-constant-expression-required-errors-for-the-generated-r-id-xxx-val